# How to calculate the centripetal force along a cartesian axis?

Tags: physics

If a centrifuge without a ballast is centered on the origin of an x-y coordinate plane, and starts at the x-axis rotating with increasing velocity counter-clockwise around the origin, how can the centripetal force of this accelerating centrifuge be calculated in the x-direction, and in the y-direction separately? This is to mathematically understand the "knocking" that is happening in an unbalanced centrifuge.

My attempt:
Look up a polar function for a spiral as the centripital force is radial, then convert to cartesian coordinates and integrate dy or dx. Attempted this but ran into the problem that for a spiral there are multiple arms of the spiral for each x or y coordinate.